# Auto event tracking help - Google Tag Manager

Tags: html, events, google-analytics, tracking, google-tag-manager

We have a banner on our website which appears to be placed in a wrapper of sorts. I'd like to trigger an event depending on which banner is being displayed.

I've deployed a click listener across all pages as well as the necessary event tag but I'm at a loss as to what the firing rule should be.

For the first banner I am using the following firing rule:

event > equals > gtm.click

element url > equals > /videos/Finding-the-right-deal/

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong?

```
<div id="content-top" class="clearfix">
    <div class="content-slider">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <ul>
                                    <li><a href="/videos/Finding-the-right-deal/">
                    <img src="Images/banner-video.png" alt="See Country can help you find the right mortgage deal"  /></a> </li>

                   <li><a href="/mortgages/help-to-buy/">
                    <img src="Images/htb.png" alt="Help to buy"  /></a> </li>

                   <li><a href="/mortgages/" id="ctl00_ConBody_AdPosition1Link">
                    <img src="Images/whatmortgagewinnerbanner.png" id="ctl00_ConBody_AdPosition1Image" alt="Award winning advice" /></a> 
                    </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--content-slider -->
```

Comment: The rule seems correct, so the problem must be somewhere else. Simon Ahava has a nice article about competing event listeners (http://www.simoahava.com/analytics/dont-gtm-listeners-work/) so if there is javascript in your site that uses click listeners this might be worth looking into.

Answer (score 0):

Try chaning the second condition of your rule from `equals` to `contains`. gtm.elementUrl returns the complete url, not just the url path.

Comment: Hey Blexy, I gave that a try... No luck sadly.

Comment: Can you share the site?

Comment: I currently don't have GTM in a live environment I can share with you, Blexy.

Is there anything I should look out for?

Comment: I found the cause of the problem. Element url is set to the source of the child image rather than href of the clicked link.

changing the second part of the rule to the below fixed the problem. 

element url > contains > Images/banner-video

Comment: Ah, glad you found it. I think that was mentioned in the article that @Eike Pierstorff sent over. I thought you had the tag firing on gtm.linkClick which is why I recommended the contains.